# Angular 6 - Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

Tags: angular

I am getting this error for a jsonp request:

```
Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.
```

Not sure how to use the callback.

```
  getSellers(): Observable<Seller[]> {
    return this.http.jsonp<Seller[]>(this.apiRoot + '/sellers', 'callback')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('fetched sellers')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getSellers', []))
      );
  }
```

Error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "JSONP Error", url: "http://localhost:4300/api/sellers?__ng_jsonp__.__req$%7Bthis.times%7D.finished=ng_jsonp_callback_0", ok: false, …}
error: Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback. at HTMLScriptElement.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:7224:32) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36916:33) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:36) at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:47) at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:34) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:14) at HTMLScriptElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17)
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4300/api/sellers?__ng_jsonp__.__req$%7Bthis.times%7D.finished=ng_jsonp_callback_0: 0 JSONP Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "JSONP Error"
url: "http://localhost:4300/api/sellers?__ng_jsonp__.__req$%7Bthis.times%7D.finished=ng_jsonp_callback_0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getSellers(): Observable<Seller[]> {
return this.http.get(this.apiRoot + '/sellers')
  .pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log('fetched sellers')),
    catchError(this.handleError('getSellers', []))
  );
```

}

Comment: thats not jsonp

Comment: getSellers(): Observable<Seller[]> {
return this.http.jsonp(this.apiRoot + '/sellers', "callback")
  .pipe(map(res => { reutrn res.results.map(item => { return new Seller( item.name, item.id ) }) })
    tap(_ => console.log('fetched sellers')),
    catchError(this.handleError('getSellers', []))
  );

Answer (score 0):

I just re-formatting my answers

```
 getSellers(): Observable<Seller[]> {
   return this.http.jsonp(this.apiRoot + '/sellers', "callback")
          .pipe(
            map(res => { 
              reutrn res.results.map(item => {
                  return new Seller( 
                    item.name, 
                    item.id 
                    ); 
                });
            })

            tap(_ => console.log('fetched sellers')),
            catchError(this.handleError('getSellers', []))
          );
```